# How to configure git to pull from one repository and push to another

Tags: git

I have two remote repositories: a main repository and a fork, and want to pull new changes from the main repo and push to my fork so I can create pull-requests to the main repo.

I know it is posible to add both remotes using `git remote add <name> <url>` but I don't want to explicitly do `git pull <main_repo>` and `git push <fork_repo>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git remote set-url --push origin <fork_repo>
```

After doing that you can check urls with this command

```
git remote -v
```

and you'll see something like

```
origin <main_repo> (fetch)
origin <fork_repo> (push)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this is to add the main repository as the "origin" remote:

```
git remote add origin <main_repository_url>
```

Or if already exists:

```
git remote set-url origin <main_repository_url>
```

Then set the fork as the push url of the remote:

```
git remote set-url --push origin <fork_repository_url>
```

Just to check the results:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  <main_repository_url> (fetch)
origin  <fork_repository_url> (push)
```

And now it is possible to pull/checkout branches from the main repository and push changes to the fork.